# print a binary tree on its side

Tags: python, tree, formatting

How can you print a binary tree on its side so the output looks like this?

```
   __/a
__/  \b
  \   _/c
   \_/ \d
     \e
```

<sub>(Prettier ascii-art welcome)</sub>

Here's some code that doesn't quite work:

```
def print_tree(tree):
    def emit(node,prefix):
        if "sequence" in node:
            print "%s%s"%(prefix[:-1],node["name"])
        else:
            emit(node["left"],"%s_/ "%prefix.replace("/ "," /")[:-1].replace("_"," "))
            emit(node["right"],"%s \\ "%prefix.replace("\\ "," \\")[:-1])
    emit(tree,"")
```

Which outputs this:

```
      _/hg19
    _/ \rheMac2
  _/ \mm9
  /\_/bosTau4
  /  \_/canFam2
_/     \pteVam1
 \_/loxAfr3
   \dasNov2
```

*Scope creep*: it would be excellent if you could pass in a function that will return the string to print of any node; in this way, I can sometimes print information about non-leave nodes too.  So whether a node has anything to print is controlled by the function passed in as a parameter.

Here's some test-data in JSON:

```
{
    "left": {
        "left": {
            "left": {
                "left": {
                    "name": "hg19", 
                    "sequence": 0
                }, 
                "right": {
                    "name": "rheMac2", 
                    "sequence": 1
                }
            }, 
            "right": {
                "name": "mm9", 
                "sequence": 2
            }
        }, 
        "right": {
            "left": {
                "name": "bosTau4", 
                "sequence": 3
            }, 
            "right": {
                "left": {
                    "name": "canFam2", 
                    "sequence": 4
                }, 
                "right": {
                    "name": "pteVam1", 
                    "sequence": 5
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    "right": {
        "left": {
            "name": "loxAfr3", 
            "sequence": 6
        }, 
        "right": {
            "name": "dasNov2", 
            "sequence": 7
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? I can imagine it to involve computing the tree's properties (depth, width, et cetera), layout computation and generating the ASCII art.

Comment: @SimeonVisser added some broken code

Comment: Looking at this makes me think that you should be tracking the tree depth as well.  I have some rudimentary code based on your broken code, but it looks terrible.  For each row, I try to figure out how much additional space it should have, but the reconstruction for that row currently only accounts for the lowest branch

Comment: have you considered serializing the tree using graphviz language? there are many layout/rendering tools that understand this format

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I'd really like to avoid external dependencies, although I am a fan of graphviz

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3056968 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/801740 and http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/11/23/visualizing-binary-trees-with-graphviz/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's some code that implements the general, recursive approach described elsewhere.  The internal representation of a tree is either a string (leaf) or a tuple (pair) of sub-nodes.  The internal representation of the intermediate "fragment" of a node is the tuple `(above, below, lines)`, where `above` and `below` are number of lines above and below the root, and `lines` is an iterator over each partial line (without spaces to the left).

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.3

from itertools import chain
from random import randint


def leaf(t):
    return isinstance(t, str)

def random(n):
    def extend(t):
        if leaf(t):
            return (t+'l', t+'r')
        else:
            l, r = t
            if randint(0, 1): return (l, extend(r))
            else: return (extend(l), r)
    t = ''
    for _ in range(n-1): t = extend(t)
    return t

def format(t):
    def pad(prefix, spaces, previous):
        return prefix + (' ' * spaces) + previous
    def merge(l, r):
        l_above, l_below, l_lines = l
        r_above, r_below, r_lines = r
        gap = r_below + l_above
        gap_above = l_above
        gap_below = gap - gap_above
        def lines():
            for (i, line) in enumerate(chain(r_lines, l_lines)):
                if i < r_above:
                    yield ' ' + line
                elif i - r_above < gap_above:
                    dash = '_' if i - r_above == gap_above - 1 else ' '
                    if i < r_above + r_below:
                        yield pad(dash + '/', 2 * (i - r_above), line)
                    else:
                        yield pad(dash + '/', 2 * gap_below - 1, line)
                elif i - r_above - gap_above < gap_below:
                    if i < r_above + r_below:
                        yield pad(' \\', 2 * gap_above - 1, line)
                    else:
                        spaces = 2 * (r_above + gap_above + gap_below - i - 1)
                        yield pad(' \\', spaces, line)
                else:
                    yield ' ' + line
        return (r_above + gap_above, gap_below + l_below, lines())
    def descend(left, t):
        if leaf(t):
            if left:
                return (1, 0, [t])
            else:
                return (0, 1, [t])
        else:
            l, r = t
            return merge(descend(True, l), descend(False, r))
    def flatten(t):
        above, below, lines = t
        for (i, line) in enumerate(lines):
            if i < above: yield (' ' * (above - i - 1)) + line
            else: yield (' ' * (i - above)) + line
    return '\n'.join(flatten(descend(True, t)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for n in range(1,20,3):
        tree = random(n)
        print(format(tree))
```

Here's some example output:

```
          _/rrrr
        _/ \_/rrrlr
       / \   \rrrll
     _/   \_/rrlr
    / \     \rrll
   /   \   _/rlrr
  /     \_/ \rlrl
_/        \_/rllr
 \          \_/rlllr
  \           \rllll
   \        _/lrrr
    \     _/ \lrrl
     \   / \_/lrlr
      \_/    \lrll
        \   _/llrr
         \_/ \llrl
           \_/lllr
             \_/llllr
               \lllll
```

And a bit more asymmetric one that shows, perhaps, why I don't pad lines with spaces to the left until the end (via `flatten`).  If the lower half had been padded on the left some of the upper arm would cross the padded area.

```
               _/rrrrr
             _/ \rrrrl
           _/ \rrrl
         _/ \_/rrlr
        / \   \rrll
       /   \_/rlr
      /      \rll
     /        /lrrr
    /       _/  _/lrrlrr
   /       / \_/ \lrrlrl
  /       /    \lrrll
_/      _/     _/lrlrrr
 \     / \   _/ \lrlrrl
  \   /   \_/ \lrlrl
   \_/      \lrll
     \      _/llrrr
      \   _/ \llrrl
       \_/ \llrl
         \lll
```

It's the "obvious" recursive algorithm - the devil is in the details.  It was easiest to write without the "_", which makes the logic slightly more complex.

Perhaps the only "insight" is `gap_above = l_above` - that's saying that the right "arm" has the length of the right side of the left subtree (you'll need to read that a few times).  It makes things relatively balanced.  See the asymmetric example above.

A good way of understanding things in more detail is to modify the `pad` routine to take a character instead of `' '` and give a different character for each call.  Then you can see exactly which logic generated which space.  This is what you get using A. B, C and D for the calls to pad from top to bottom, above (obviously there's no character when the amount of space is zero):

```
             _/rrrr
            / \rrrl
          _/B _/rrlrr
         / \_/ \rrlrl
        /AA  \rrll
      _/BBB  _/rlrrr
     / \DD _/ \rlrrl
    /AA \_/ \_/rlrlr
   /AAAA  \C  \rlrll
  /AAAAAA  \_/rllr
_/AAAAAAAA   \rlll
 \DDDDDDDD   _/lrrrr
  \DDDDDD  _/ \lrrrl
   \DDDD  / \lrrl
    \DD _/B _/lrlrr
     \_/ \_/ \lrlrl
       \C  \lrll
        \_/llr
          \lll
```

There's more explanation [here](http://www.acooke.org/cute/Printingbi0.html) (although the tree is very slightly different).

Comment: Beautiful!  Please do link to the blog post.  One stretch goal would be to be able to control the string used for the - at each branch, and for them to be able to be variable length.

Comment: post at http://www.acooke.org/cute/Printingbi0.html - it's very similar code, but without the "_" and with more comments.  you can work out how to add an arbitrary string by comparing the two.

Answer (score 2):

Make a representation structure, involving a string array and a line number of the "petal".

rep(leaf) is [0, repr(leaf value)]

rep(nonleaf), given `top = nonleaf.left` and `bottom = nonleaf.right`:

Pad each line of rep(top) with spaces if above top's petal, or with slash at an appropriate position if below. Similarly, pad each line of rep(bottom) with spaces if below bottom's petal, or with backslash at an appropriate position if above. repr(nonleaf) is then [height of top, padded lines of top followed by padded lines of bottom].

Example:

```
rep(a): [0, ["a"]]
rep(b): [0, ["b"]]
rep(ab): [1, ["/"+"a", "\"+"b"]]
rep(c): [0, ["c"]]
rep(d): [0, ["d"]]
rep(cd): [1, ["/"+"c", "\"+"d"]]
rep(e): [0, ["e"]]
rep(cde): [2, [" "+"/c", "/" + "\d", "\" + "e"]]
rep(abcde): [2, [" "+"/a", "/"+"\b", "\ "+" /c", " \" + "/\d", "  " + "\e"]]
```

Note that in top case, the width of the padding is the number of lines below petal; in the bottom case, the width of the padding corresponds to petal. Thus, in (abcde) case, top has 2 lines and petal 1, so padding is (2 - 1 == 1) one character; bottom has petal 2, so padding is 2 characters.

If you want, you could also add an "_" at each nonleaf at (petal-1)th line (and an extra space to all other lines).

Obviously, none of this is code ("\" is a syntax error waiting to happen), but it should not be too difficult to implement from here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to approach this recursively, and track the sizes of the individual subtrees. In particular, where the root is. A non-balanced tree can easily look like this:

```
/
\/
 \/
  \/
   \
```

Now consider you already have built this tree, what do you need to transform this to the following when adding the parent level.

```
  /
 /\/
/  \/
\   \/
 \   \
  \
```

The key idea is to start with the leaves. They are trivial. Then define a way to aggregate two subtrees, given they have a different amount of lines and a different position of the subtree root node.

Comment: Its an approach but aren't you kind of glossing over the hard part? ;)

Comment: Well, I have given you the key ideas: leaf-to-root, keeping track of the size and subtree root position. You'll have to figure out the exact string operations yourself.
I don't have the code ready for you. This is how I solved this 10 years ago when plotting genealogy trees by outputing raw postscript. Even if I would be able to dig up this code, it would be rather useless to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice sideways tree that just helped me in debugging a project:
http://www.acooke.org/cute/ASCIIDispl0.html

Results resemble the directory layout of the VIM NERDtree plugin if you've seen that.

Here is my re-implementation as a `__str__` method in a binary tree:

```
def __str__(self):
    """Recursive __str__ method of an isomorphic node."""
    # Keep a list of lines
    lines = list()
    lines.append(self.name)
    # Get left and right sub-trees
    l = str(self.left).split('\n')
    r = str(self.right).split('\n')
    # Append first left, then right trees
    for branch in l, r:
        # Suppress Pipe on right branch
        alt = '| ' if branch is l else '  '
        for line in branch:
            # Special prefix for first line (child)
            prefix = '+-' if line is branch[0] else alt
            lines.append(prefix + line)
    # Collapse lines
    return '\n'.join(lines)
```